# What is the best approache for making the offline native android app

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, sharedpreferences, android-volley

I want a suggestion to make the **offline mode** b/w these two approachs

> **1. Caching,**
>
> **2. Storing the data in db or SharedPreferences.**

If I talk about caching the, *I am using the volley for the rest api in the app.*
*Volley has its own cache option to store the data which can be used while the net has not connected.*

And second thing is the *storing the json data in db or sharedPreferences and can get access while net has'nt connected*.

So please anyone may give any suggestion what is better option to create the app with offline mode.

And one more thing if I have choosed the second option then what is better

> **DB using sqlite**

or

> **SharedPreferences**

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have a solid understanding of how the service's cache memory is managed I wouldn't recommend using it as offline data storage.

Comment: @zgc7009 I have not solid understanding therefor i am asking the question on so. And I only want suggestion not solution. So please if you have any idea about it let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the data you want to store and the kinds of operation you want to do with these data.

**If you are going to store a huge mount of data** DataBase using [Sqlite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) or [realm](https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm/) is the best choice for you .As the data is structured and managed by the database, it can be queried to get a sub set of the data which matches certain criteria using a query language like SQL

**Shared Preferences** I advise you to do not use it only for small data,simple strings or primitives .furthermore you cannot really search within the data except you have a certain concept for naming the keys.

If you are keeping it simple, JSON in preferences can be very quick and extremely easy to implement. In terms of security, preferences are slightly more "exposed" than a database in that they are simply stored in xml, but ultimately the database file for an SQLite database is stored the same way and can be read during an intrusion as well

Comment: Thanks brother for explaining it. What about the cache, is caching used for making the offline mode apps.

Comment: @AmanGupta Yes it is .But you should have a good background knowledge on how to manage it .

Comment: Ok Thanks once again.